# Unable to add elements to array of array that are mutable lists in koltin

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin

I am trying to add mutable list array of elements to another another mutable list of array of array. Here I have values inside `locationList` as mutable list of LatLng pairs like this([lat/lng:(some value,some value),lat/lng:(some value,some value),lat/lng:(some value,some value)]). I am trying to add the list to `locationlists4` every time function is called. But I am getting elements only in the last list of the array `locationlists4[location4.size-1]`(like this [[],[],[lat/lng:(some value,some value),lat/lng:(some value,some value),lat/lng:(some value,some value)]). All other array lists are empty.

```
   var locationList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()

    var locationlists4 =  mutableListOf<MutableList<LatLng>>()




        private fun onPauseButtonClicked(){


        locationlists4.add(locationlist)
}
```

```
    private fun updateLocationList(location: Location) {
        val newLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        locationList.value?.apply {
            add(newLatLng)
            locationList.postValue(this)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you add lat long to `locationList`.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: ``locationList`` looks like a ``LiveData`` to me, not a mutable list. Are you sure this is the right code?

Comment: I got it right. Seems that I was right all the time. I had to clear the `locationList` every time the function was called. That was the reason why `locationList` was not added to `locationlists4`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```kotlin
    var locationList = mutableListOf<LatLng>()

    var locationlists4 =  mutableListOf<LatLng>()

    private fun onPauseButtonClicked() {
        locationlists4.addAll(locationlist)
    }
```

Have a look [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add-all.html) for more info.

Comment: Still not getting added. I tried this code `locationlists4.addAll(listOf(locationList))`